# Block elements not centering on Windows but are centering on OSX

Tags: html, css

I've been searching the forums here for awhile but havent had any luck with this.

I coded up my launch page with a subscription form. You can find it live here - cyclefoundry.com

On my `OSX 10.10.3` everything looks fine. The form is email address centred on the screen on my `Firefox` and `Chrome`. The form is inheriting the text align assignment in the body.

However a friend pointed out that on `Windows 8` using `Firefox` the form is aligned to the left. You can see here http://screencast.com/t/en59dCe0h

I've tried to enter this using a variety of methods but am lost.

Can anyone help? Sorry for the n00b question, i'm just starting out.

Comment: a tip would be to remove your site link/url quite fast if you dont want unnessary traffic to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line in your css -

## mc_embed_signup_scroll { display: inline-block;   text-align: center; width: 100%; }

Comment: Thanks you very much. This did it. I understand now what I did wrong. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In your css, `#mc_embed_signup form` have `text-align: left;` set it to `text-align: center;` and it should work.